# How to push data to couchdrop sftp using R?

Tags: r, curl, ftp, sftp, data-transfer

I have recurring data that I pull from my server in a template and then I need to send that to the client to couchdrop.io which is a SFTP service. I am not familiar with that platform and need this community's help on it.

I researched quite a bit and learned that I need **RCurl** package and use `ftpUpload` command for this. In the `ftpUpload` parameters, I am struggling to figure the format of "to" or the destination where the data needs to be send. I have the file and the user password. Let's say following is the sample info:

```
what = test_df  
username = testadmin  
pass = adminpwd  
https://sftp.couchdrop.io/
```

How would the connection and data transfer code look like?

I keep getting the following error as well `Error in file(what, "rb") : invalid 'description' argument`

Since this is my first post, please forgive me if the format is incorrect or if I need to provide more info.
Thanks!!